# ORA-25188: cannot drop/disable/defer the primary key constraint for index-organized tables or sorted hash cluster

Tags: oracle, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a migration script to disable the constraints of list of table that going to migrate.

```
    FOR I IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC, TMP_DATA_MIG_TABLE_LIST TDM
  WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = TDM.TABLE_NAMES) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||I.TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||I.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' CASCADE';
  END LOOP;
```

Wonder there have 9 tables I couldn't drop the constraint due to ORA-25188 and IOT, if I remain them without dropping constraint, it will encounter unique constraint violated.

Comment: What is your question? You can't drop the primary key on IOTs, as you seem to know and the error message is telling you.

Comment: I would like to disable the constraints on these IOT tables, anyway I can acheive?

Comment: You cannot. The message tells you so. IOTs are indexes, if you disable the index you have nothing left.